# Flutter StreamBuilder Firebase Bad state: Stream has already been listened to error

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout, stream-builder

I know some posts came with the solution of this error but I still dont understand how can i use StreamController without bloc. I do not use bloc pattern in my code, all of the solutions somehow related on bloc pattern.

I have two tab and when i click tab, shows data correctly but when i click second time on tab it shows this error. Solutions are using Stream controller or behaviour subject but i dont understand how to use.

error: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.

Thanks in advance.

home_page.dart

```
StreamBuilder<List<Dashboard>>(
                stream: _dashboardService.getData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) return buildWaitingScreen();
                            return ListView.builder(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () => onPressCard(
                                        snapshot.data[index], user),
                                    child: Card(
                                      elevation: 10,
                                      child: Container(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                                        child: Text(
                                          '${snapshot.data[index].name}',
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                });
                },
              ),
```

dashboard_service.dart

```
  Stream<List<Dashboard>> getData() async* {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> sharedDashboardsStream = _databaseService.sharedDashboards;

    List<Dashboard> dashboards = List();
    await for (var sharedDashboard in sharedDashboardsStream) {
      for (var sharedDahsboardDoc in sharedDashboard.documents) {
        Dashboard dashboard;
        if (sharedDahsboardDoc["dashboardId"] != null) {
          DocumentSnapshot dashSnapshot =await _databaseService.getDashboard(sharedDahsboardDoc["dashboardId"]);
          dashboard = Dashboard(id: dashSnapshot.documentID, ownerId:dashSnapshot["ownerId"] ,name: dashSnapshot["name"] );
        }
        dashboards.add(dashboard);
      }
      yield dashboards;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using stream.toBroadcastStream() so it can be listened to multiple times. Even if you don't have multiple listners at once, once you listened to a stream you can never listen to it again unless it is a broadcast stream.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but i can not get all data when listen twice. changing tab second time no data available on stream. I wanna get all data every time when i come back to tab again @Mike

Comment: Wait that's not supposed to happen. The data should still be there, are you using the same stream?